# Как сообщение пользователя положить в переменную бот aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, variable

У меня есть бот на aiogram
Я хочу принимать сообщения отправленные пользователем в переменную, а затем ее проверить.
Как это сделать?
Например в telebot я делаю так:

> mes = message.text.lower()

Comment: Пожалуйста дайте развернутый ответ

Comment: Я правильно понял что вы спрашиваете как узнать что за сообщение отправил пользователь?

Comment: @Никита Да, правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример простого эхо-бота на aiogram:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

from config import TOKEN 
# В файле config.py создайте переменную TOKEN
# и присвойте ей свой токен от бота.


bot = Bot(token=TOKEN) #Инициализация бота
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Этот декоратор будет реагировать на
# сообщения что вы присылали боту.
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    # В переменной msg.text
    # содержится текст сообщения
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp) # Запуск основного цикла
```

Comment: Спасибо огроменное! а немогли бы вы подсказать, я новичок в aiogram, что такое машина состояний? FSM

Comment: Простите, но я сам не знаю. Я подробно не изучал aiogram. Про это можете почитать в интернете.

Comment: Например здесь: https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/